# format time in php when results are from a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have an event agenda set up to populate from a database, echoing rows from a loop.

I see how to format to get the time that I want: date("g:i a") BUT I can't seem to make it work within my php code.

I'm having the loop print the data to a $row, and then specifying which piece of data like this:

```
    <td>' .$row['start_time'] . '</td>
```

In which start_time is the column in my database that is the datetime piece of data.

I've tried a few different ways of adding in the formatting for the date time, but none of them have successfully returned results. How do I format this code so it will show up? Do I make it a function or can I add it to the line I have here?

I'd like to just return the time (not the date), and have it be something like 7:00am.

Thank you!

Edit to add: Here is more code that may shed light on where I'm struggling:

```
   $conn = new DatabaseConn();

   $query = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE date=\"2012-10-21\" AND visible=\"1\" ORDER BY agenda_id;";

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if($result){

    $numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    $data = array();
    $flist = array();

        for($i=0;$i<$numfields;$i++)$flist[] = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
        $data[0] = $flist;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

         $data[] = $row;
         echo '
         <tr>
          <td id="time">'. $row['start_time']) . '</td>
          <td id="time">' . $row['end_time'] . '</td>   
          <td id="title">' . $row['title'] . '</td>
          <td id="description">' . $row['description'] . '</td>
          <td id="room">' . $row['room'] . '</td>
          <td id="type">' . $row['attendee_type'] . '</td>          
         </tr>
         ';
        }
```

Edit #2 to add: Here's my output on the test page:
(copied the view source instead of just the page)

```
    <tr>
     <td id="time">2012-10-21 14:00:00 </td>
     <td id="time">2012-10-21 20:00:00</td>
     <td id="title">Registration</td>
     <td id="description">Open registration and conference check-in.</td>
     <td id="room">Lobby</td>
     <td id="type">all</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: First of all why is there a quote mark after the first td? I think that would convert it to a string.

Comment: With the above code, what is your output? Post that as well.

Comment: Add it as the html from view source.

Comment: Using `strtotime`, it should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
echo date("g:i a", $row['start_time']); //$row['start_time'] should be Unix timestamp
```

Otherwise use

```
echo date("g:i a", strtotime($row['start_time']));
```

**[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** parses `English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp`

Go through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to know about all date `format` characters.

Comment: I'll edit my OP to include more code- I do understand what you're saying and tried it; however I seem to be missing some sort of formatting principle.

Comment: echo date("g:i a", strtotime($row['start_time']));

Worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`date('g:i a', strtotime($row['start_time']));` // if $row['start_time'] is a valid timestamp